# line breaks inside of a textarea

Tags: php

I am having something strange happen.

My script is for editing information.
When I send the $_POST from my textarea to my php page. It sanitizes and inserts correctly, but I also want to re-output the data if called upon again. So i am basically using jquery $post to send and retrieve the information.

It all works great, except when I call the info back with the edit button and function "onmousedown" it is not giving me the correct format for my parameters.

If I only write on one line it comes out perfect, but if I use multiple lines it won't retain the line breaks and it chops off the closing " ' " so the function cannot be reset. Any ideas? Here is my callback echo. Thanks in advance...

The problem is in the "$againList" parameter...

```
$againList = $_POST['updated_songList']; // I am sending back the exact same data that was given without filter...
echo '<span><h4 style="margin-bottom:0px; font-size:14px;">'.$full_birthday.'
    <a href="#" onclick="deleteSongList('.$songid.');" style="color:gray; float:right; font-weight:100; font-size:12px;">delete</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="editSongList(\''.$songid.'\', \''.$againList.'\');" style="margin-right:5px; color:gray; float:right; font-weight:100; font-size:12px;">edit</a></h4>'.$song_list.'<br /></span>';
```

If you need anything else let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out and got it running. Thanks for all the help everyone!

The problem seems to be that you must at least add the "stripslashes" function to a $_POST before you can place it into a javascript parameter otherwise, I seems like at every '\n' it stops the function call and give the error "there is an unterminated string literal" meaning your last parameter does not have an " ' " at the end of it. I am not sure why though. If anyone has any insight, I would appreciate the learning experience.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: My guess is that you have [magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) turned on. "When on, all ' (single-quote), " (double quote), \ (backslash) and NULL characters are escaped with a backslash automatically. This is identical to what addslashes() does." **I strongly recommend you turn magic quotes off.**

Comment: Read [Disabling Magic Quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)

Comment: @Herbert Thanks! Found that earlier... You learn something new everyday, except on SO. Here you learn something new every minute! I love SO!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, php has a nl2br() function that converts new line to breaks but I'm not sure that's what you are after. Does the linebreaks dissapear before or after they come to the php script?

Here is how to use nl2br();

```
$var = nl2br($_POST['myValue']);
```

Comment: After. Also, you are correct, I am not looking for nl2br, I need to retain the /n when I call it back.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what you mean with retaining the /n... could you explain further? Perhaps post some more code? (on the vote: I didn't think it was you, I just commented at the same time to whoever downvoted :P)

Comment: When I post the information, I want to sanitize it on one hand and on the other I want to send it back so that I can repeat the process without refresh. The problem is in the edit button. The script sends the info back and cuts off the " ' " so it comes back as an unterminated string literal

Comment: Hmm, maybe it gets stripped out. Did you try using htmlspecialchars()?

Comment: Okay, so nevermind I got it going, thanks. I guess the problem is that I have to sanitize the string before it can be used as a string parameter. Thanks for the help anyway. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @JuanGonzales: It's permissible to supply an answer to your own question _and accept it_. It could be useful to others who may have a similar problem in the future.

Comment: What answer it is supposed to be? "Do not delete linebreaks if you want to keep them?"

Comment: @Herbert I always try to answer my own problems when I find a solution, but my reputation is still low so I have to wait at least 4 hours, but I will post it right now. Also Col. Shrapnel, I wasn't deleting any line breaks, they were being omitted on there own.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$againList = nl2br($_POST['updated_songList']);
```

Basically, all textarea newlines are "\n" which HTML doesn't show. nl2br() just converts them into `<br/>` while displaying them. The newlines remain intact.

For the script that removes the "'" from the end, unless you show that script, you can't be helped.